# A row of galaxy note 3 screen is not responsive

Tags: touchscreen, samsung-galaxy-note-3, broken-screen

The area goes right across the keyboard,  leaving the phone useless.

S-pen still works fine.

I used TSP Dot mode to show the issue in this screen shot:

[image: Screenshot]

Please tell me the hardware isn't shot. I sure do love this phone.

Comment: I've tried the typical soft/hard restarts. Also observed the same issue in safe mode.

Comment: Did you drop your phone or did it get wet?

Comment: @superthomaslab small drops and minor wetness throughout the two years I've had it, but, it hasn't had any drops or gotten wet in the past month or more. This issue just started two days ago.

Comment: "Please tell me the hardware isn't shot." It sounds like you already know the answer to your question but you don't want to accept it.

Comment: @DanHulme that's just a hunch. I've seen crazier things happen before.

Comment: Try anything that [sur007](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/15197/part-of-touch-screen-is-not-working) has listed. It's worth a shot.